Unknown encoder 'h264_videotoolbox'
I'm facing an issue with FFmpeg on my iOS app. When I use the mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl pod, hardware-accelerated video encoding with h264_videotoolbox works perfectly. But, when I try to use a prebuilt FFmpeg binary, I receive the following error:
Unknown encoder 'h264_videotoolbox'
I have created a build script to compile FFmpeg for iOS with VideoToolbox support. Here’s a portion of my configure command:
./configure \
  --cross-prefix="${HOST}-" \
  --sysroot="${SDK_PATH}" \
  --prefix="${FFMPEG_LIBRARY_PATH}" \
  --pkg-config="${HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" \
  --arch="${TARGET_ARCH}" \
  --cpu="${TARGET_CPU}" \
  --target-os=darwin \
  ${ASM_OPTIONS} \
  --ar="${AR}" \
  --cc="${CC}" \
  --cxx="${CXX}" \
  --as="${AS}" \
  --ranlib="${RANLIB}" \
  --strip="${STRIP}" \
  --nm="${NM}" \
  --extra-ldflags="$(get_min_version_cflags)" \
  --disable-autodetect \
  ${BUILD_LIBRARY_OPTIONS} \
  ${SIZE_OPTIONS} \
  --disable-xmm-clobber-test \
  ${DEBUG_OPTIONS} \
  --disable-neon-clobber-test \
  --enable-version3 \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-pic \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-videotoolbox \
  --enable-decoders \
  --enable-encoders \
  --enable-muxers \
  --enable-demuxers \
  --enable-parsers \
  --enable-protocols \
  --enable-filters \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-hwaccels \
  --enable-decoder=h264_videotoolbox \
  --enable-encoder=h264_videotoolbox \
  --enable-encoder=hevc_videotoolbox \
  ${CONFIGURE_POSTFIX} 1>>"${BASEDIR}"/build.log 2>&1

I use the following command to execute in FFmpeg:
let command: [String] = [
    "-y",
    "-hide_banner",
    "-i", inputPath,
    "-c:v", "h264_videotoolbox",
    "-vf", "scale=1080:1920",
    "-acodec", "aac",
    outputPath
]

What might be missing in my build configuration to cause h264_videotoolbox to be unrecognized? Are there any specific steps to ensure that the VideoToolbox encoder is enabled properly in a prebuilt FFmpeg binary for iOS?
Any suggestions on solving this issue would be appreciated!
